# Dynamic column name in update query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTr4C.png)[image]

Week 1 Data will be replace every week and updated to according in next table.
I have two tables where one table has dynamics auto increment column name(using sequence). This query I am using in SSIS OLE DB command. where as source of this query is conditional split.

I have tried running this query with manual update operation but still it is not working for this above query it is showing me incorrect syntax error. 
I tried giving fixed column name then Data flow working properly but after providing dynamics update it stop working.

```
declare @nu nvarchar(50),@nae nvarchar(50),@sql nvarchar(max)
execute sp_executesql  N'SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences',@nu OUTput
```

Note:-Output of above Code is 16

```
set @sql='update test2 set Week19'+@nae'=5 where id= 2384'
exec @sql
```

It will be great if you can help me to update this table automatically by automatically detecting changing column name by sequence.

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_update

Comment: This seems like a pretty rogue data model.  That said, sample data and desired results would help your question.

Comment: I'm thinking the `@nae` variable is interpreted as an integer. Try `Cast(@nae as varchar)` in the `Update` statement. See if that works for you. And I agree with @Gordon Linoff, that this is model that you could have downstream nightmares.

Comment: @WEI_DBA tired this but it stows me error that could not find store procedure. declare nu nvarchar(max),nae nvarchar(max),sql nvarchar(max)
execute sp_executesql  N'SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences',@nu OUTput
set  nae=nu 
set sql='update test2 set Week19'+Cast(nae as varchar)+'= 5 where id= 2384;'
exec sql